# Undefined Variable: mysqli error when connecting to database

Tags: database, page-template

I know this question has been asked before, but the solutions have not been working for myself. I am receiving this error while trying to connect to a database from within a wordpress template file.
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /Path to file/ on line 11

From what I have read it is a global variable issue but I have tried adding the global $mysqli inside the function with no success and I already pass it through the function so I am stumped. Thank for any insight you can provide.

**Connection File**

```
<?php
//Connection for the Pathways database
//Establish Our Connection
define('DB_HOSTNAME','host');   //DATABASE HOST
define('DB_USERNAME','username');   //DATABASE USERNAME
define('DB_PASSNAME','password');   //DATABSE PASSWORD
define('DB_APPNAME','name');    //DATABASE NAME

function connectDB($mysqli){
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSNAME, DB_APPNAME);
    if(!$mysqli){
        trigger_error ('<p class="error">Could not connect to the Apprenticeship Pathway\'s Database at this time. Please try again later.</p>'.mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{
        return $mysqli;
    }
}   
?>
```

**Output File**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="entry-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php
                if(!mysqli_connect_errno()){
                    if($stmt = $db_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM apprenticeship")){
                        //Bind Parameters
                        $stmt->bind_param('issssssss', $id, $profile_pic, $first_name, $last_name, $school, $p_1, $p_2, $p_3, $p_4);
                        //Execute
                        $stmt->execute();
                        //Store Results
                        $stmt->store_result();
                        //Get the rows
                        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
                        //Bind the results
                        $stmt->bind_result($id, $profile_pic, $first_name, $last_name, $school, $p_1, $p_2, $p_3, $p_4);

                        if($stmt->num_rows < 1){
                            echo'<p class="error">Apprenticehsip Pathways are available at this time</p>';
                        }else{
                            while($stmt->fetch()){
                                echo '<article id="apprenticeship-'.$id.'" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pathways-container">';
                                    echo '<figure>';
                                        echo' <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#apprenticeship-'.$id.'-contents">';

                                            echo '<img src="'.$profile_pic.'" alt="'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'">';
                                        echo'</a>';
                                        echo '<figcaption>'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'</figcaption>';
                                    echo'</figure>';

                                    echo '<div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="apprenticeship-'.$id.'-contents" aria-labelledby="'.$last_name.'">';
                                        echo '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">';
                                            echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>';
                                            echo '<h4 id="'.$last_name.'">'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'</h4>';
                                            echo '<p class="pathway-school"><strong>'.$school.'</strong></p>';
                                            echo '<div class="pathway-content">';
                                                if($p_1 != NULL){
                                                    echo '<p>'.$p_1.'</p>'; 
                                                    }
                                                if($p_2 != NULL){
                                                    echo '<p>'.$p_2.'</p>'; 
                                                }
                                                if($p_3 != NULL){
                                                    echo '<p>'.$p_3.'</p>'; 
                                                }
                                                if($p_4 != NULL){
                                                    echo '<p>'.$p_4.'</p>'; 
                                                }
                                                echo '<div class="modal-footer">';
                                                    echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
                                                echo '</div>';
                                            echo'</div>';
                                        echo '</div>';
                                    echo'</article>';
                            }//End While    
                        }//End Else
                    }else{
                        echo '<p class="error">There was a problem connection with the Apprenticeship Pathway. Please try again later.</p>';
                    }
                }//End if no connection error
                else{
                    echo '<p class="error">There was a problem making the connection. Please try again later.</p>';
                }
                ?>
                </div><!--End column-->
            </div><!--End row-->
        </div><!--End entry-content-->
    </div><!--end container-->
</div><!--End content-wrapper-->
```

Comment: Use the $wpdb global for database calls. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: That worked, All i did was swap out my $mysqli variable with $wpdb and presto. thanks!